# "Circular dependency between the following tasks" MultiModule Error

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, dependency-management, multi-module

i am refactoring my project MVP pattern to MVVM pattern and i create a new java module for this. For example i have views like SplashActivity, LoginActivity and MainActivity.

I changed LoginActivity and presenter class to new LoginActivity and viewmodel class and keep in new module. In the existing flow Splash -> Login-> Main but Login class is new class with viewmodel in new module. So i need to implament both side dependency.

So When i add implementation project(':features') in app module gradle and implementation project(':app') in features module gradle, i am getting  "Circular dependency between the following tasks" error.

How can i fix that? or can anybody tell me new solition approach MVP to MVVM desingn pattern update.

Thanks.

Circular dependency between the following tasks:
:app:processDebugResources
--- :features:processDebugResources
--- :app:processDebugResources (*)

I am getting error like this.

Answer (score 1):

This problem usually occurs when each module depends on each other directly or indirectly.That's why you cannot build the project because the compiler dont know which one compiles first. Let me explain with this image.

[image]

If you wanna fix that you should remove that circular implementation from the dependencies you have .

Let me show an approch that you could implement following a multi module project: Here is an image

[image]

Comment: Actually the only reason i created new module is MVP to MVVM update, so i don't need to common module. When i during update, can i use single module maybe i can use different package. Is it well solition ?

Comment: @ozanurkan yes you dont need to create a common module, Its just in case you need it. If in your case dont needed go ahed and try it